# Pointer field not behaving as expected in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree

The following is an example code where I am unable to root cause the error.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int value;
    node* left;
    node* right;
    node* parent;

    node()
    {
    }

    node(int value)
    {
        this->value = value;
        this->left = NULL;
        this->right = NULL;
        this->parent = NULL;
    }
};



int coun = 0;

void check(node** root)
{
    if(coun == 0)
    {
        coun++;
        check(&((*root)->right));
    }

    else
    {

        node *parentOfCurrent,*childOfCurrent;
        parentOfCurrent = (*root)->parent;
        childOfCurrent = (*root)->right;
        cout << "Value before the statement" << (*root) << "\n";
        parentOfCurrent->right = childOfCurrent;
        cout << "Value after the statement" << (*root) << "\n";
    }
}



int main()
{
    node *node1,*node2,*node3,*node4,**temp,*temp2;
    node1 = new node(1);
    node2 = new node(2);
    node3 = new node(3);
    cout << "Node1 Node2 Node3" << node1 << " " << node2 << " " << node3 << "\n";
    node1->right = node2;
    node2->right = node3;
    node2->parent = node1;
    node3->parent = node3;

    check(&node1);

    //cout << node2->value;
}
```

In this example I have created a tree [as descibed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTvUY.png)
I am trying here trying to assign node1's right field to node3. 
The procedure I am following is :

- 1) Passing node1's address(double pointer) to the function check.
- 2) Since, coun = 0, it is incremented to coun = 1, and called again
  this time passing the address of node2.
- 3)In this call the statement

`parentOfCurrent->right = childOfCurrent`;
is executed.

This statement intends to assign the .right field of node1 to node3. What is happening is it value of *root before and after the statement is different.

```
Value before the statement: 0x9e17b8
Value after the statement: 0x9e6f30
```

What is happening is that the **pointee of** **parentOfCurrent->right which is (*root) is being set to childOfCurrent**, but I am unable to explain why is this happening?

Comment: Please comment if I am unclear in expressing my question and what more details are required

Comment: Specifically you are missing to present a [MCVE] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: You also should read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and you will almost certainly be able to answer your own question.

Comment: `root` points to `node1->right`, which is `parent->right`, as parent of `node2` is `node1`. You assign `parent->right`, so `*root` changes. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Why do you pass a pointer to pointer to `check()`?

Comment: I had expected &(parent->right) to point to the address of node2, hence the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this "tree":

```
  1 
 /\
x  2
   /\
  x  3
```

When you enter the recursion, `root` holds the address of `1`'s right pointer.

```
  1 
 /\
x  2  <-- *root (root == &node1->right)
   /\
  x  3
```

`parentOfCurrent->right` points to `1`'s right child (it has the same value as `*root`).
`childOfCurrent` points to the `3` node.

After the assignment, `root` is still the address of `1`'s right pointer, but `1`'s right child is now the `3` node:

```
  1 
 /\
x  3  <-- *root (root == &node1->right)
   /\
  x  x
```

The double pointer indirection seems unnecessary here.
Try this:

```
void check(node* root)
{
    if(coun==0)
    {
        coun++;
        check(root->right);
    }
    else
    {   
        node *parentOfCurrent, *childOfCurrent;
        parentOfCurrent = root->parent;
        childOfCurrent = root->right;
        cout<<"Value before the statement"<<root<<"\n";
        parentOfCurrent->right = childOfCurrent;
        cout<<"Value after the statement"<<root<<"\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    node *node1,*node2,*node3;
    node1 = new node(1);
    node2 = new node(2);
    node3 = new node(3);
    cout<<"Node1 Node2 Node3"<<node1<<" "<<node2<<" "<<node3<<"\n";
    node1->right = node2;
    node2->right = node3;
    node2->parent = node1;
    node3->parent = node2;  // You had a bug here, making node3 its own parent. 
    check(node1);
    cout << node1->right->value; // Prints 3
}
```

Note that you also want to adjust the parent pointer of a node that you're moving, but I left that out.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)!! One more doubt, if I had to pass the address of node2, how would I go about it?